# Find the direction of rotation of a sprite i.e. clockwise or anticlockwise

Tags: iphone, ios, vector, cocos2d-iphone

I've been beating myself at this because I think its an easy problem but somehow I just can't find a solution to it.

I'm rotating a CCSprite about its anchor point depending on touch move events. Here is the code I use to rotate the sprite.

```
CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]];
CGPoint newLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

//preform all the same basic rig on both the current touch and previous touch
CGPoint previousGlLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:previousLocation];
CGPoint newGlLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:newLocation];

CCSprite *handle = (CCSprite*)[_spriteManager getChildByTag:HANDLE_TAG];

CGPoint previousVector = ccpSub(previousGlLocation, handle.position);
CGFloat firstRotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(previousVector);
CGFloat previousTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(firstRotateAngle);

CGPoint currentVector = ccpSub(newGlLocation, handle.position);
CGFloat rotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(currentVector);
CGFloat currentTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(rotateAngle);

float rotateAmount = (currentTouch - previousTouch);
handle.rotation += rotateAmount;
```

I need to somehow find what is the direction of rotation i.e. is the direction clockwise or anticlockwise. I tried doing this by setting up an 'if' condition on the rotateAmount value. But this does not work in one specific case.

For eg. If the user is rotating the sprite in the clockwise direction, in this case the rotateAmount value will be positive from 0 - 359. The moment the user is about to complete the circle the condition would not hold true and the direction would change to anticlockwise.

Is there a better way of detecting the direction of rotation?

Comment: instead of measuring the whole rotation, try measuring the recent rotation. (i.e. if the last 5 samples of rotation took you from 350° to 5°, …)

Comment: I need to play a different sound in the counter clockwise direction. Hence I need to detect the direction on every move event. Taking few samples won't work!

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: added elaboration as an answer (so that i could format it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this wrap-around sanity check:

```
float rotateAmount = (currentTouch - previousTouch);

if (rotateAmount > 180)
  rotateAmount -= 360;
else if (rotateAmount < -180)
  rotateAmount += 360;

handle.rotation += rotateAmount;
```

Comment: that amount of times I've tried to write this same logic so much less elegantly.... thanks so much +1 for you sir